# In the MySQL host-name does the '%' in '%.exemple.com' covers the main domain 'exemple.com' as well or only its subdomains?

Tags: mysql, permissions, domain

In the MySQL host-name does the `%` in `%.exemple.com` covers the main domain `exemple.com`as well or only its subdomains?

For instance in this

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'rep'@'%.exemple.com';
```

will the `exemple.com` domain be allowed as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html#:%7E:text=The%20%25%20and%20_%20wildcard%20characters%20are,in%20the%20mysql.com%20domain.)

> The % and _ wildcard characters are permitted in host name or IP
> address values. These have the same meaning as for pattern-matching
> operations performed with the LIKE operator. For example, a host value
> of '%' matches any host name, whereas a value of '%.mysql.com' matches
> any host in the mysql.com domain

Will the `exemple.com` domain be allowed with the `%.mysql.com` ?

No, it will not.

The %.mysql.com expect some host from the domain mysql.com , for example:

```
h1.mysql.com
h2.mysql.com ...
```

You could find useful information [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-access.html)